# How can i put a whole array of pixels on screen with pygame?

Tags: python, arrays, pygame, pixel

With javascript and canvas you can fill an array with color for each pixel and then put it on the screen. How can i do this in python using pygame? A very small example is enough.

Comment: I tried using pixel array but the pixels get put on screen as soon as I give them values, like pixelarray[1][1]=(0,0,0). But it isn't very efficient for what I want to do. I need to make they array and then put it all in a single operation.

Comment: You can create a new Surface, draw on that, and then blit it back to the window's Surface.

Comment: surfarray might actually be your best bet.  Also, pixelarray is not being inefficient.  It's just a view of the underlying surface data.  Assuming you care about the surface anyway, pixelarray will actually be *fastest*!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick example I whipped up:

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *

arr=[]
RED=(255,10,10)
BLU=(10,255,10)
GRN=(10,10,255)
arr.append(RED)
arr.append(BLU)
arr.append(GRN)
SCREEN_X=100
SCREEN_Y=100

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_X, SCREEN_Y))
square=pygame.Surface((1, 1))

for j in range (SCREEN_Y):
    for i in range (SCREEN_X):
        num=random.randint(0,2)
        square.fill(arr[num])
        draw_me=pygame.Rect((j+1), (i+1), 1, 1)
        screen.blit(square,draw_me)
pygame.display.flip()
```

I filled an array with red blue and green, then randomly choose a colour to draw.

Hope it helps